# Changing UINavigationBar later in View Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller that does not have a NavigationController (and can't). I define a navigation bar like this.

```
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 41)];

    navBar.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x72CE97);
    navBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x72CE97);

    //Keep the container for Navigation Items
    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    UIImage* logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_logo_small.png"];
    navItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logoImage];

    //Add the left button as an Item to Navigation Items

    UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButton:)];
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;

    //Add Navigation Items Container to Navigation Bar
    navBar.items = @[ navItem ];

    //Display the Navigation Bar
    [self.view addSubview:navBar];
    [navBar release];
```

How do I change the background later in the View Controller? 
Below doesn't work. I think it is because I don't have a NavigationController:

```
NavigationBar *navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:197.0f/255.0f green:174.0f/255.0f blue:135.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:197.0f/255.0f green:174.0f/255.0f blue:135.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: Yes, it is because you don't have a NavigationController and you are getting `self.navigationController.navigationBar;`

make a global variable for `UINavigationBar *navBar` or use tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 41)];
navBar.tag = 1;
...
NavigationBar *navigationBar = (NavigationBar *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

Comment: I think this is the answer but it says "Incompatible pointer type assign to 'UINavigationBar *' from 'UIView *'.  Can I cast this to a UINavigationBar?

Comment: Yes, simply to resolve it: `NavigationBar *navigationBar = (NavigationBar *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];`

Comment: @lr100 It's safe that cast the view of  `viewWithTag` returns